# Multi-router Network Setup

Tags: networking, router

I have the following setup:

- Home with a fibre connection, several wired devices and numerous wireless devices
- Home office with a separate fibre connection, samba server with dhcpd, various wired Linux and Windows servers and workstations, printers and scanners

I want the two buildings to use their own fibre connections, but I want to connect the two networks so that the house can use office resources (printers, networks drives) and I can RD/VNC to the servers.

A later improvement may be some load balancing.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Is it the same physical location? Otherwise a VPN would be one option.

Comment: lots of options, depending on existing router locations.  gigE drop between the two and static routes is probably the best-performing option; some sort of wifi bridge the worst.  could even setup a router-to-router vpn over the fibre connections as @seth suggests (could be better performance than gigE, but will be unavailable whenever your ISP uplinks are down).

Comment: It is the same property (adjacent buildings), but each with their own fibre connection.
There is a cat-6 cable available between the buildings. Previously when I tried to connect the two networks, all the external traffic went through the one office router.

Comment: I assume gigE drop is an ethernet connection?

Office is currently 192.168.10.*
House is 192.168.20.*
If I connect the two together (say 192.168.10.*), where do I set the static routes? I am happy to supply all addresses from dhcpd (which I am investigating modify to provide time restrictions on leases to specific devices). How do I tell the routers to send external traffic through their own connections? For example, I don't want Netflix in the house using my office connection.